# Relative density of images of diophantine polynomials

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry

My current research project involves sampling a sequence along non-constant polynomials with non-negative integer coefficients defined over the natural numbers, and I'd like to be able to say when two such polynomials are "independent".

Say for two polynomials of this type $p$ and $q$, that $q$ is independent of $p$ if
\begin{equation*}
\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{p(\mathbb{N}) \bigcap q(\mathbb{N}) \bigcap \{1,2,\ldots,n\}}{p(\mathbb{N})\bigcap \{1,2,\ldots,n\}} = 0
\end{equation*}

That is, $q$ is independent of $p$ if the relative upper asymptotic density of the image of $q$ in the image of $p$ is $0$. Say $q$ is dependent on $p$ if this property does not hold.

It's pretty easy to show that if $\deg(q)>\deg(p)$ then $p$ is independent of $q$ (though $q$ is not necessarily independent of $p$). However, I'm stuck classifying when $p$ and $q$ are independent when they are of the same degree. If we define $g_{mr}(n) = mn+r$, it seems like if $\deg(q)=\deg(p)$, then $p$ and $q$ are dependent on each other if and only if there exist $m$, $m'$, $r$, $r'$ such that $q \circ g_{mr} = p \circ g_{m'r'}$. The forward direction is trivial, but I'm having a lot of trouble with the reverse direction.

This problem can be viewed as a diophantine equation of the form $p(n)-q(m)=0$, and I'd like to know how these solutions are distributed. Unfortunately, all papers I've found that might be relevant have only classified whether there are finitely or infinitely many solutions. Even for quadratics it seems difficult. I know there exist recurrence relations that generate further solutions given one solution, but I don't know if these generate all solutions, and I haven't been able to find any results on the subject.

Could you suggest any relevant papers or theorems that might shed some light on this problem in general, or even just for quadratics?

Comment: For quadratics, $p(n)=q(m)$ generally reduces to a form of Pell's equation, on which there is an extensive literature. The bottom line is that there may be infinitely many solutions, but they grow exponentially, so your ratio should go to zero (except in your "composition with linear" case). For higher degree, there's a theorem of Siegel which says (again, barring exceptional cases) that $p(n)=q(m)$ has only finitley many solutions, which again makes your ratio go to zero.